# A verb to convey "taking no notice to something for awhile"

Tags: word-request

I was wondering which verb is usually used instead of the bold verb below:

> - During my journey to that country, I hired a bicycle. When I was taking some pictures at the X square, I just **took no notice** to my bicycle for a few seconds, and as soon as I turned my face it was vanished into thin air; I even didn't realize how they stole it!

In the sentence above, I have no idea what (phrasal)verb normally is used to indicate "usually" a short period of unawreness of something or taking no notice to something or paying no attention to something often because you are distracted or paying attention to something/someone else?

Please help me to find the proper verb for this meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

> I ***glanced*** *away from* my bicycle (and when I looked back it was gone).

From Merriam-Webster:

> **4 a** of the eyes : to move swiftly from one thing to another
>   **4 b** : to take a quick look at something
>   // *glanced* at his watch

Since *glance* already implies quickly or briefly, adding *for a few seconds* isn't actually necessary, and the sentence can be shortened considerably.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the idiom:

> "I **took my eyes off** my bike for a few seconds."

According to [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/take-your-eyes-off):

> **take your eyes off** (*phrase*) to stop looking at someone or something
>   *She only took her eyes off the child for a moment*.

Answer (score 1):

Your own suggestion,

> I just didn't pay attention to my bicycle for a few seconds

works fine. Another option would be to use [*to leave unattended*](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/leave-something-unattended):

> I just left my bicycle unattended for a few seconds

Both sound more idiomatic than 'to take no notice'.

Note that the 'short while' is already conveyed by the words 'just' and (more clearly) 'for a few seconds'. I'm not sure if there is a verb that also encompasses this time component.